# How do I load the website into the main activity window rather than a new window?

Tags: android, google-glass, gdk

I used the google glass gdk web loading example

```
 void openWebPage(String url) {         
Uri webpage = Uri.parse(url);Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, webpage);       if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) 
   {
        startActivity(intent);      
    } 
}
```

to open custom websites based on the voice prompt.  However when I swipe down to close the website, instead of closing the entire app it closes only the website and leaves the app with the main_activity window in the background.  How do I load the website in the main activity card so that when I close the website nothing is left in the background?

Answer (score 0):

Call `finish()` directly after `startActivity`:

```
if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) 
{
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}
```

This will finish (i.e., close) your activity so that the user will not return to it after closing the website.